# Deployment package for a 64-bit windows service in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, deployment, .net-4.0, 64-bit

I'm trying to create a deployment package for a windows service targeting x64.

I've made the setup project itself target x64 but I need to add custom actions to actually register/unregister the service.

However, when I add custom actions and try to run the installer, I get a `BadFormat` exception which indicates that the executable for my service is corrupted.

I suspect I'm running into the [issue mentioned here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/heaths/archive/2006/02/01/64-bit-managed-custom-actions-with-visual-studio.aspx) but am unable to prove it.

This windows service is being developed as part of a far larger application using TFS for automated builds and deployment, continuous integration, etc - So manually tweaking bits of a binary file using tools which require the use of a GUI is a definite no-no.

So... What I need to know is; Is it possible to automatically build a deployment package for a 64-bit windows service in VS2010? If so how?

Comment: Could you target 32 just to confirm that 64 is the issue?

Comment: Not with the current project - It has multiple dependencies some of which are not controlled by myself and all of which are x64. I could come up with a dummy x86 service and try that but am not sure what that would achieve as it would be lots of differences. Let me see if I can comment out enough to lose the x64 dependencies

Comment: Ok, using "Orca" to manually configure the custom actions to point at the 64-bit version of `InstallUtilLib.dll` as per the post linked in my question allows the installation to go ahead

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will happen when either your service or one of the assemblies it uses was built with the Target Platform setting changed to x86.  In which case you have to use the right version of Installutil.exe to register the service.  There are two, in c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework and \framework64, respectively the 32-bit and the 64-bit version.  Odds are good that you need the former.  If you created a Setup project then you'd change the TargetPlatform property to x86.

Also check if you really need to have the target platform set, you only do if you have a dependency on unmanaged code like a COM server.  The C# setting is in Project + Properties, Compile tab.  The default for VS2010 is x86, just flip it to AnyCPU if you have no such dependency.

Comment: We're installing in a 64-bit environment using components shared with a 64-bit web app (MVC2). All assemblies are configured to be built as 64-bit. I could use installutil to register the service but that kind of defeats the point of wrapping it all up inside an installer doesn't it? Why would I change the setup target platform to x86? If I do that, it complains that my assemblies are x64...

Comment: As I tried to explain, the source of the problem is the Target Platform setting in one of your projects.  Have you found it yet?  Using the Corflags.exe utility is another way to check the setting after building.  Targeting x64 is not useful, just target AnyCPU so that your code will run anywhere.  Note that the setting can have different values in the Debug and the Release configuration so be sure to select the right configuration.

Comment: The service in question copies assemblies which are part of the MVC app and loads them via reflection into a new app domain before running some methods. I don't have any control over the website (which is configured to be x64). If I choose "Any CPU", will it run as x64 by preference? If not, I'll be trying to load 64-bit assemblies using the 32-bit framework = exception. In this scenario, does your advice still hold true?

Comment: To explain why it's doing this: Jobs required by the website are defined in the website assemblies and implement an IJob. This service is a scheduler which detects changes to the website assemblies (publish, etc.), waits for running jobs to finish, disposes the app domain, copies the assemblies, loads the new jobs and starts tunning them again.

Comment: Yes, AnyCPU does what it says, the assembly will run regardless of the bitness of the process.  The jitter generates the appropriate kind of machine code.  There is considerable confusion about "service" vs "website" here.  If this is a true Windows service then the bitness is determined by the Platform Target setting of the service EXE project, not a web site.  And AnyCPU will always select x64 on a 64-bit operating system.  Maybe you didn't really mean Windows service.

Comment: I mean windows service (previously known as NT Service). The website is a bad place to put scheduled jobs due to stateless nature, CGI timeouts, etc - so we wanted a normal windows process to run jobs. It could've been a console/winforms but that would require a logged in user and the appropriate method seemed to be windows service. We didn't want to define jobs in multiple places but wanted to allow maximum flexibility so the windows service scans the website DLLs for classes which implement `IJob`. It then reads the attributes and runs the job when appropriate (either "locally" in the svc)..

Comment: or by creating an HTTPS connection to the website at a standard URL.

Comment: Ok, on the assumption that I really DO need the target platform set, and that all the projects are targeted to x64 - Is there any way I can get the deployment package produced by VS to use the 64-Bit version of InstallUtil?